# CUDA - Array Generating random array on gpu and its modification using kernel

Tags: visual-c++, cuda

in this code im generating 1D array of floats on a gpu using CUDA. The numbers are between 0 and 1. For my purpose i need them to be between -1 and 1 so i have made simple kernel to multiply each element by 2 and then substract 1 from it. However something is going wrong here. When i print my original array into .bmp i get this https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpdhn.png (typical noise pattern). But when i try to modify that array with my kernel i get blank black picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/tisIp.jpg . The program is executable but in the debug i get this:

> First-chance exception at 0x75f0c41f in Midpoint_CUDA_Alpha.exe:
>   Microsoft C++ exception: cudaError_enum at memory location
>   0x003cfacc..
>
> First-chance exception at 0x75f0c41f in Midpoint_CUDA_Alpha.exe:
>   Microsoft C++ exception: cudaError_enum at memory location
>   0x003cfb08..
>
> First-chance exception at 0x75f0c41f in Midpoint_CUDA_Alpha.exe:
>   Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000..

i would be thankfull for any help or even little hint in this matter. Thanks !
(edited)

```
#include <device_functions.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "EasyBMP.h"
#include <curand.h> //curand.lib must be added in project propetties > linker > input
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

float *heightMap_cpu;
float *randomArray_gpu;
int randCount = 0;
int rozmer = 513;

void createRandoms(int size){
    curandGenerator_t generator;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&randomArray_gpu, size*size*sizeof(float));
    curandCreateGenerator(&generator,CURAND_RNG_PSEUDO_XORWOW);
    curandSetPseudoRandomGeneratorSeed(generator,(int)time(NULL));
    curandGenerateUniform(generator,randomArray_gpu,size*size);
}

__global__ void polarizeRandoms(int size, float *randomArray_gpu){
    int index = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
    if(index<size*size){
        randomArray_gpu[index] = randomArray_gpu[index]*2.0f - 1.0f;
    }
}

//helper fucnction for getting address in 1D using 2D coords
int ad(int x,int y){
    return x*rozmer+y;
}

void printBmp(){
    BMP AnImage;
    AnImage.SetSize(rozmer,rozmer);
    AnImage.SetBitDepth(24);
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<=rozmer-1;i++){
        for(j=0;j<=rozmer-1;j++){
            AnImage(i,j)->Red = (int)((heightMap_cpu[ad(i,j)]*127)+128);
            AnImage(i,j)->Green = (int)((heightMap_cpu[ad(i,j)]*127)+128);
            AnImage(i,j)->Blue = (int)((heightMap_cpu[ad(i,j)]*127)+128);
            AnImage(i,j)->Alpha = 0;
        }
    }
    AnImage.WriteToFile("HeightMap.bmp");
}

int main(){
    createRandoms(rozmer);
    polarizeRandoms<<<((rozmer*rozmer)/1024)+1,1024>>>(rozmer,randomArray_gpu);
    heightMap_cpu = (float*)malloc((rozmer*rozmer)*sizeof(float));
    cudaMemcpy(heightMap_cpu,randomArray_gpu,rozmer*rozmer*sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    printBmp();

    //cleanup
    cudaFree(randomArray_gpu);
    free(heightMap_cpu);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might have some issues with float/integer conversion, try replacing the computation in your kernel with:
randomArray_gpu[index] = randomArray_gpu[index]*2.0f - 1.0f;

Comment: thx, but that didnt solve it :/

Comment: Because `int` is promoted to `float` before `*` and `+`, see [Implicit type conversion rules in C++ operators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563000/implicit-type-conversion-rules-in-c-operators).

Comment: thx Jack, but it is not it. Even when I leave the line written like this:

randomArray_gpu[index] = randomArray_gpu[index];

which should just leave the array as it was, the result is the same blank black (all zeroes).

Comment: problem was with my understanding of cuda... kernels aparently cannot access __device__ float *randomArray_gpu without the array being in the argument of the kernel function. Now that i've changed the kernel to this: __global__ void polarizeRandoms(int size, float *randomArray_gpu) it works.
Thanx again for help, i have modded the int numbers in the equation by your suggestions so you have probably saved me another headache.

Comment: @TomášTomusJavorský I was not suggesting Reguj's solution, but explaining why his solution was not working. You do not need to cast the numbers to `float`. Anyway, I come to the same conclusion. For some reasons, `polarizeRandoms` has no visibility of `randomArray_gpu` and one "workaround" is to pass the pointer to the `__global__` function. There is something I'm perhaps overlooking, since this is the same problem as in [CUDA global (as in C) dynamic arrays allocated to device memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79121/cuda-global-as-in-c-dynamic-arrays-allocated-to-device-memory).

Comment: Ah thanx again :) Anyway i'll try to keep that rules in mind for the future.

Comment: @TomášTomusJavorský: Please **do not** "fix" code in your questions. The whole point of [SO] is to leave a question and its answer for the next person who comes along. By "fixing" code, you are effectively destroying the question and making the answers you have received invalid. I have rolled back your edits and corrected the title as you wanted. Please don't edit the code again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
cudaMalloc((void**)&randomArray_gpu, size*size*sizeof(float));
```

We don't use `cudaMalloc` with `__device__` variables.  If you do proper cuda [error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api) I'm pretty sure that line will throw an error.

If you really want to use a `__device__` pointer this way, you need to create a separate normal pointer, `cudaMalloc` that, then copy the pointer value to the device pointer using `cudaMemcpyToSymbol`:

```
float *my_dev_pointer;
cudaMalloc((void**)&my_dev_pointer, size*size*sizeof(float));
cudaMemcpyToSymbol(randomArray_gpu, &my_dev_pointer, sizeof(float *));
```

Whenever you are having trouble with your CUDA programs, you should do proper cuda error checking.  It will likely focus your attention on what is wrong.

And, yes, kernels *can* access `__device__` variables without the variable being passed explicitly as a parameter to the kernel.

The [programming guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#device-variable-qualifier) covers the proper usage of `__device__` variables and the api functions that should be used to access them from the host.

Comment: thx, again, fixed now. And yes this was allso in the debug output.

Comment: Definitely right. It was too late yesterday to have enough neurons working to realize that there was a `__device__` keywork in front of the pointer declaration :-)